# What are the candidate keys in the below relation

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database, functional-dependencies

`R(A,B,C,D,E)` Functional Dependencies = `{AC->E,B->D,E->A}`

I know ABC is a candidate key.Can BC be a candidate key too?

Comment: What happens when 1. you look at the definition of "CK" or 2. you use the method you used for finding the first CK to finding all the other CKs?

Comment: The question in your title is not the question in your question. What is your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition of "candidate key" is a superkey that does not contain another superkey. So a candidate key does not contain another candidate key.

Answer (score 0):

I could tell that BC is not a candidate key. For (ABC)+, you could get the attribute D and E through the functional dependency and thus you get a key by involving all the attributes.

However, for (BC)+, you could only get D, you cannot get A or E. Thus, BC is not a candidate key.